# OpenTK stencil buffer

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk, stencil-buffer

I'm new to opengl and I'm struggling to get the stencilbuffer to work for a simple case;
I have two textures, one being a bitmap and one being a "mask", with which I'm trying to hide some parts from the bitmap.

I can't seem to get this to work, when I try to set the stencil format on creating my stencil texture using GL.TexImage2D I get an invalid enum, and when I try to attach a stencilextension to FramebufferTexture2D for the fbo I draw my mask in:

```
GL.Enable(EnableCap.StencilTest);
GL.ClearStencil(0);
GL.StencilMask(0xFFFFFFFF); // read&write

// Create stencil texture
GL.GenTextures(1, out stencilTexture);
GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, stencilTexture);
GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba8, stencilTextureWidth, stencilTextureHeight, 0, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Rgba, PixelType.UnsignedByte, IntPtr.Zero);
//DOES NOT WORK: GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, (PixelInternalFormat)All.StencilIndex, stencilTextureWidth, stencilTextureHeight, 0, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.StencilIndex, PixelType.UnsignedByte, IntPtr.Zero);

CREATE COLORTEXTURE FROM BITMAP

// Create a FBO and attach the stencil texture
GL.Ext.GenFramebuffers(1, out fbo);
GL.Ext.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt, fbo);
GL.Ext.FramebufferTexture2D(FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt, FramebufferAttachment.ColorAttachment0Ext, TextureTarget.Texture2D, stencilTexture, 0);
//DOES NOT WORK?: GL.Ext.FramebufferTexture2D(FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt, FramebufferAttachment.StencilAttachmentExt, TextureTarget.Texture2D, stencilTexture, 0);

DRAW SOME STUFF INTO THE STENCILTEXTURE TO FUNCTION AS A MASK

GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.StencilBufferBit);

DRAW COLOR TEXTURE

GL.Enable(EnableCap.StencilTest);
GL.ClearStencil(0);
GL.ColorMask(false, false, false, false);
GL.StencilFunc(StencilFunction.Always, 1, 1);
GL.StencilOp(StencilOp.Keep, StencilOp.Keep, StencilOp.Replace);

DRAW THE STENCIL TEXTURE

GL.Disable(EnableCap.StencilTest);
```

I can't seem to find any examples that demonstrate this for a simple 2d case (masking textures using textures).

EDIT:
Updated version here: http://pastebin.com/iuur2UTM

Comment: That's an awful lot of code. Can you make the problem more specific?

Comment: Sorry, I provided the entire example so it could run out of the box, as I'm not sure where the problem lies... I editted the original post to only include the relevant parts and linked the full source code which should compile.

Comment: Why vote this down, just because he provided alot of code? After reading a lot of questions here, it's good to see people giving some time and effort into their questions and providing what they have. To find a proper answer. I hate adding a comment which always reads like "please post your draw method" etc. This is defintely not a question worth downvoting.

Comment: @dowhilefor Before ranting, look at the edits. There were three HUNDRED lines of code when my comment was posted, hence why I asked to make the problem more specific, hence why his downvote has been removed after he fixed his question. There's a difference between time and effort and posting all of your code.

Comment: @arasmussen Well you are right, that was a little bit to fast and to harsh, sorry for that. And you are of course correct, but sometimes i see quickly downvotes, because some people don't like certain parts about the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't render to an FBO and expect stencil operations to work *unless* you actually attach a buffer with stencil to it. FBOs only have the buffers you give them.

Since you're using the EXT version of FBO, you have to check for the presence of the [EXT_packed_depth_stencil](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/packed_depth_stencil.txt) extension. If that's there, then you can do the following (note: this is C. You'll have to translate it to OpenTK and C# code):

```
GLuint renderBuffer;
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &renderBuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_EXT, stencilTextureWidth, stencilTextureHeight);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_EXT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBuffer);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_EXT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBuffer);
```

That should help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunatly I still can't get it to work (I'm a opengl noob and can't seem to find any references on how to achieve something like this). I translated the code you gave above to the opentk equivalent:
GL.GenRenderbuffers(1, out stencilTexture);
GL.RenderbufferStorage(RenderbufferTarget.Renderbuffer, RenderbufferStorage.StencilIndex8Ext, stencilTextureWidth, stencilTextureHeight);
GL.BindRenderbuffer(RenderbufferTarget.Renderbuffer, stencilTexture);

I pasted the full source here: http://pastebin.com/rPzKgvDj

Comment: @Martijnh: That's not the OpenTK equivalent of what I posted. You used the StencilIndex8 format, when I told you to use GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8. You have to use the combined depth and stencil format. Also, what I posted has an obvious bug that I have now corrected.

Comment: I changed it, but it warns about an invalid operation: http://pastebin.com/iuur2UTM

Are these the correct steps to achieve masking a texture by a stencil renderbuffer?:
*   enable stencil capability
*   create renderbuffer (with stencil attachments)
*   create color texture
*   create fbo and attach stencil renderbuffer & colortexture

in draw loop:

*   enable stencil
*   clear stencil
*   draw color texture
*   set stencil ops
*   draw stencil
*   disable stencil

Comment: @Martijnh: Did you see what I changed in my post? Because you didn't make that change in your code.

Comment: ahem, it should now: http://pastebin.com/VNQ7qqzR  Still getting no result & the invalid operation though...